# Spring 3.x - how do I redirect from a mapping that returns data?

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-mvc

I have a method in my controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="getData", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<MyDataObj> getData()
{
  return myService.getData();
}
```

The data is returned as JSON or xsl, depending on the request.

If the person making the request is not authorized to access the data I need to redirect the user to a "not authorized" page, so something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="getData", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<MyDataObj> getData()
{
  if (!isAuthorized())
  {
    // redirect to notAuthorized.jsp
  }
  return myService.getData();
}
```

All the examples I've seen using Spring require the method to return either a `String` or a `ModelAndView`. I thought about using `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()` but all my JSPs are under WEB-INF and can't be reached directly.

How can I deny access gracefully to the data request URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more elegant solution may be [to use a `HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) which would check for authorization, blocking any requests which are not permitted to proceed. If the request then reaches your controller, you can assume it's OK.

Comment: This didn't work because I have my method annotated with `@ResponseBody`. All I got with the `RedirectView` object in JSON. I'm looking at the `HandlerInterceptor` now.

Comment: @Paul: Good point.  I've edited my answer to remove that bit.

Comment: I had to rework my directory structure a little (I had everything under `/`) but using an interceptor worked great, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is below. But your particular case would rather to handle with other approach.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response someMethod(String someData, HttpServletResponse response){
    if(someData=="redirectMe"){
       response.sendRedirect(ppPageUrl);
    }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is filter. You can move all security logic into filter and keep clean code in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple:

Send a error status to the client

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
```

and handle the same with you ajax callback handler and redirect. :)

Comment: If no Ajax then as e-zinc and skaffman suggested you should go for prehandle, check for authorization and use redirect view.